# Android: How to get image files from directory into view.setBackgroundDrawable()

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an app that can take images from a directory on the android phone and display them in a layout. I seem to be working my way towards a solution in a backwards manner. I know to use `view.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(String pathName));` to display the image, but I don't know how to get the image's path from the directory.

I have a vague idea of what to do, but would appreciate clarification on this matter. I think the next step is to use:

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
}
```

But how do I filter the files so that only image files get stored in my `file[]`? Such as .png or .jpg/.jpeg files? And after that, should I use `files[].getPath` or `files[].getAbsolutePath`? I would store the result in a `String[]`.

What I am mainly asking for is verification that the above code should work. And also, how I might filter to store only image files such as `.png`, `.jpg` and `.jpeg`.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to do something like this for filtering:

```
File[] file = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {

                    return filename.contains(".png");
                }
            });
```

If you want the filepath of the image of lets say the file at `file[0]`, you would do this:

`file[0].getAbsolutePath();`

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code worked, with a few modifications. I used `File file[] = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {});`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement a [FileFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileFilter.html) and pass it to [listFiles](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29). You can create one that filters out only image files as you specified.

EDIT: and you want to use `getAbsolutePath()` as the argument to `createFromPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for only to get .Png ,.jpg files and containing floders

```
private File[] listValidFiles(File file) {
    return file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            File file2 = new File(dir, filename);
            return (filename.contains(".png") || filename.contains(".jpg") || file2
                    .isDirectory())
                    && !file2.isHidden()
                    && !filename.startsWith(".");

        }
    });
}
```